# Assigning values to records in a dataframe based on datetime column being between a reference datetime range

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frames:

period_df:

```
Group1 Group2    Period           Start time             End time
G1     G2  Period 1  1900-01-01 05:01:00  1900-01-01 06:00:00
G1     G2  Period 2  1900-01-01 06:01:00  1900-01-01 07:00:00
G1     G2  Period 3  1900-01-01 07:01:00  1900-01-01 08:00:00
G1     G2  Period 4  1900-01-01 08:01:00  1900-01-01 09:00:00
G1     G2  Period 5  1900-01-01 09:01:00  1900-01-01 10:00:00
```

records_df:

```
Group1 Group2        Original time
G1     G2  1900-01-01 05:05:00
G1     G2  1900-01-01 07:23:00
G1     G2  1900-01-00 07:45:00
G1     G2  1900-01-02 09:57:00
G1     G2  1900-01-02 08:23:00
```

I want to assign the corresponding `Period` from `period_df` to each record in `records_df`, based on the `Group1` and `Group2` columns and the time being between `Start time` and `End time`.

I wrote the following function to do that:

```
def assign_period(record):
    for _, period in period_df.iterrows():
        if record['Group1'] == period['Group1'] and \
        record['Group2'] == period['Group2'] and \
        period['Start time'] <= record['Original time'] <= period['End time']:
            return period['Period']
    return None
```

And when I use the function to assign periods to the records I get the following output:

```
records_df['Period'] = records_df.apply(assign_period, axis=1)

Group1 Group2        Original time    Period
G1     G2  1900-01-01 05:05:00  Period 1
G1     G2  1900-01-01 07:23:00  Period 3
G1     G2  1900-01-00 07:45:00      None
G1     G2  1900-01-02 09:57:00      None
G1     G2  1900-01-02 08:23:00      None
```

Some records don't get assigned a period because the date is either a day before or after the dates mentioned on reference `period_df` dataframe.

The expected output is for Periods to be assigned irrespective of the date:

```
Group1 Group2        Original time    Period
G1     G2  1900-01-01 05:05:00  Period 1
G1     G2  1900-01-01 07:23:00  Period 3
G1     G2  1900-01-00 07:45:00  Period 3
G1     G2  1900-01-02 09:57:00  Period 5
G1     G2  1900-01-02 08:23:00  Period 4
```

How can I also incorporate a check for records that are not assigned a period in the above function to either go a day ahead or before and match up with the `Period` from `period_df`?

```
import pandas as pd
period_df = pd.DataFrame({
                'Group1': [
                    'G1',
                    'G1',
                    'G1',
                    'G1',
                    'G1'],
                'Group2': [
                    'G2',
                    'G2',
                    'G2',
                    'G2',
                    'G2'],
                'Period': [
                    'Period 1',
                    'Period 2',
                    'Period 3',
                    'Period 4',
                    'Period 5'],
                'Start time': [
                    '1900-01-01 05:01:00',
                    '1900-01-01 06:01:00',
                    '1900-01-01 07:01:00',
                    '1900-01-01 08:01:00',
                    '1900-01-01 09:01:00'],
                'End time': [
                    '1900-01-01 06:00:00',
                    '1900-01-01 07:00:00',
                    '1900-01-01 08:00:00',
                    '1900-01-01 09:00:00',
                    '1900-01-01 10:00:00']})

records_df = pd.DataFrame({
                'Group1': [
                    'G1',
                    'G1',
                    'G1',
                    'G1',
                    'G1'],
                'Group2': [
                    'G2',
                    'G2',
                    'G2',
                    'G2',
                    'G2'],
                'Original time': [
                    '1900-01-01 05:05:00',
                    '1900-01-01 07:23:00',
                    '1900-01-00 07:45:00',
                    '1900-01-02 09:57:00',
                    '1900-01-02 08:23:00']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

at first chk your typo in example code of records_df

your code has '1900-01-`00` 07:45:00','1900-01-`02` 09:57:00'

use following code to fix typo

```
data = {'Group1': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1', 2: 'G1', 3: 'G1', 4: 'G1'},
 'Group2': {0: 'G2', 1: 'G2', 2: 'G2', 3: 'G2', 4: 'G2'},
 'Original time': {0: '1900-01-01 05:05:00',
  1: '1900-01-01 07:23:00',
  2: '1900-01-01 07:45:00',
  3: '1900-01-01 09:57:00',
  4: '1900-01-01 08:23:00'}}
record_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Step1**

make dtype to datetime

```
records_df['Original time'] = pd.to_datetime(records_df['Original time']) 
period_df['Start time'] = pd.to_datetime(period_df['Start time']) 
period_df['End time'] = pd.to_datetime(period_df['End time'])
```

**Step2**

make bins

```
bins = period_df['Start time'].tolist() + [period_df['End time'].tolist()[-1]]
```

`bins`

```
[Timestamp('1900-01-01 05:01:00'),
 Timestamp('1900-01-01 06:01:00'),
 Timestamp('1900-01-01 07:01:00'),
 Timestamp('1900-01-01 08:01:00'),
 Timestamp('1900-01-01 09:01:00'),
 Timestamp('1900-01-01 10:00:00')]
```

**Step3**

make Period column by `pd.cut` (using `bins`)

```
records_df.assign(Period=pd.cut(records_df['Original time'], 
                                bins=bins, right=False, 
                                labels=period_df['Period']))
```

output:

```
Group1  Group2  Original time   Period
0   G1  G2  1900-01-01 05:05:00 Period 1
1   G1  G2  1900-01-01 07:23:00 Period 3
2   G1  G2  1900-01-01 07:45:00 Period 3
3   G1  G2  1900-01-01 09:57:00 Period 5
4   G1  G2  1900-01-01 08:23:00 Period 4
```

---

if its not typo use timedelta dtype instead datetime

```
s = pd.to_timedelta(records_df['Original time'].str.split(' ').str[1]) 
s1 = pd.to_timedelta(period_df['Start time'].str.split(' ').str[1]) 
s2 = pd.to_timedelta(period_df['End time'].str.split(' ').str[1])

bins = s1.tolist() + [s2.tolist()[-1]]

out = records_df.assign(Period=pd.cut(s, bins=bins, right=False, labels=period_df['Period']))
```

`out`

```
Group1  Group2  Original time   Period
0   G1  G2  1900-01-01 05:05:00 Period 1
1   G1  G2  1900-01-01 07:23:00 Period 3
2   G1  G2  1900-01-00 07:45:00 Period 3
3   G1  G2  1900-01-02 09:57:00 Period 5
4   G1  G2  1900-01-02 08:23:00 Period 4
```

Comment: that is not a typo. There are odd records in my data frame which is why I want to figure out how to assign periods based on these records

Comment: @z star 1900-01-00 was crazy data, so I thought it was a typo.

Comment: important thing : use `pd.cut` by changing dtype that allows `pd.cut`.  We cannot use datetime because of data such as 1900-01-00, but we can use timedelta to separate only the time part and can do same. There is no problem. i update it.